# How to prevent TimeoutError on asyncio when making large amounts of API calls

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, jupyter-notebook, python-asyncio

*I'm new to the asyncio module. Until recently I used to use requests for the task I'm about to write about.*

I'm trying to scale a script I work with which works well with up to 120 calls on Requests. However, with request being single threaded, it would take forever to get 1000 API calls (which is what I'm trying to achieve). This is where I found asyncio which makes asynchonous requests.

This is a script I put together for asyncio with the help of this [article](https://betterprogramming.pub/asynchronous-programming-in-python-for-making-more-api-calls-faster-419a1d2ee058).

```
url = 'https://api.url.com/search?api_key=api_key&api_params=multiple_params'
queries = ['online slots', 'metaverse', 'sports betting', 'basketball odds', 'soccer odds', 'online poker', 'best casinos in germany', 'barbecue grills', 'outdoor pizza ovens']
results = []
def get_tasks(session):
    tasks=[]
    for q in queries:
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(session.get(url.format(q), ssl=False)))
    return tasks
timeout = ClientTimeout(total=500)
async def get_queries():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(timeout=timeout) as session:
        tasks = get_tasks(session)
        responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        for response in responses:
            results.append(await response.json())
        
asyncio.run(get_queries())
```

It seems to work fine in most instances. But, it seems to timeout on many occasions. When I'm using the German queries and when it is making more than 500 API calls.

Below is what I keep getting back. As you can see in the script I've added a client timeout.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-8c48df090394> in <module>
     33             results.append(await response.json())
     34 
---> 35 asyncio.run(get_queries())

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nest_asyncio.py in run(future, debug)
     30         loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
     31         loop.set_debug(debug)
---> 32         return loop.run_until_complete(future)
     33 
     34     if sys.version_info >= (3, 6, 0):

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nest_asyncio.py in run_until_complete(self, future)
     68                 raise RuntimeError(
     69                     'Event loop stopped before Future completed.')
---> 70             return f.result()
     71 
     72     def _run_once(self):

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/asyncio/futures.py in result(self)
    176         self.__log_traceback = False
    177         if self._exception is not None:
--> 178             raise self._exception
    179         return self._result
    180 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/asyncio/tasks.py in __step(***failed resolving arguments***)
    278                 # We use the `send` method directly, because coroutines
    279                 # don't have `__iter__` and `__next__` methods.
--> 280                 result = coro.send(None)
    281             else:
    282                 result = coro.throw(exc)

<ipython-input-4-8c48df090394> in get_queries()
     29     async with aiohttp.ClientSession(timeout=timeout) as session:
     30         tasks = get_tasks(session)
---> 31         responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
     32         for response in responses:
     33             results.append(await response.json())

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/asyncio/tasks.py in __wakeup(self, future)
    347     def __wakeup(self, future):
    348         try:
--> 349             future.result()
    350         except BaseException as exc:
    351             # This may also be a cancellation.

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/asyncio/tasks.py in __step(***failed resolving arguments***)
    280                 result = coro.send(None)
    281             else:
--> 282                 result = coro.throw(exc)
    283         except StopIteration as exc:
    284             if self._must_cancel:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py in throw(self, arg)
   1123 
   1124     def throw(self, arg: BaseException) -> None:  # type: ignore[arg-type,override]
-> 1125         self._coro.throw(arg)
   1126 
   1127     def close(self) -> None:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py in _request(self, method, str_or_url, params, data, json, cookies, headers, skip_auto_headers, auth, allow_redirects, max_redirects, compress, chunked, expect100, raise_for_status, read_until_eof, proxy, proxy_auth, timeout, verify_ssl, fingerprint, ssl_context, ssl, proxy_headers, trace_request_ctx, read_bufsize)
    557                             resp = await req.send(conn)
    558                             try:
--> 559                                 await resp.start(conn)
    560                             except BaseException:
    561                                 resp.close()

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py in start(self, connection)
    911                 if self._continue is not None:
    912                     set_result(self._continue, True)
--> 913                     self._continue = None
    914 
    915         # payload eof handler

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/helpers.py in __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)
    719 
    720         if exc_type is asyncio.CancelledError and self._cancelled:
--> 721             raise asyncio.TimeoutError from None
    722         return None
    723 

TimeoutError:
```

Can anyone help me figure what I'm doing wrong? And how to avoid timeouts for large amounts of API calls on asyncio?

Much appreciated!